# Create multiple custom HTML pages

Tags: pages, html

I need to make a few unique "landing" pages each with unique designs. They will each be one off.

I am looking for a way to organise these pages.

What I used to do is have a subfolder in the theme directory called "pages" with a list of php files for example the homepage would be `if is "homepage" then show this html`.

Then I would simple include each "page" in my functions.php file. I don't think this is the accepted way to do things.

Some pages would be "homepage", "pedagogy", "results" etc... how can I organise these static HTML pages without them being in the root of my theme like `page-homepage.php` or `page-results.php`?

Or is the `functions.php` include method viable?

Answer (score 0):

You can created pages within wordpress itself and then assign a custom template.

You may store the template files however you like as long as they are wihtin the theme folder itself.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/